# Spring Boot Not Application Not Working For JDBC In Liberty Server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, websphere-liberty

I am new to Spring Boot.

I am trying to write a rest api which should take data from database and display it to consumer. I don't know how to tackle with this issue.

Please help to run the application with JDBC datasource on Liberty Server. Simple spring boot rest service working perfectly fine.

Please forgive me in case there so much have asked in question. I want to learn this.

here is my pom file :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.ankit.demo</groupId>
<artifactId>test-demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>test-demo</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>true</skip>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

DemoService.java

```
package com.ankit.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.MessageSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jpa.JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.ankit.demo.*" })
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = MessageSourceAutoConfiguration.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class,   JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class })
public class DemoService extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder  application) {
        return application.sources(DemoService.class);
    }
}
```

OracleDatabaseConfiguration.java

```
package com.ankit.demo.configuration;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.JndiDataSourceLookup;

@Configuration
public class OracleDatabaseConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.Oracle.datasource.jndi-name}")
    private String jndiName;

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "")
    public DataSource OracleDataSource() {
        JndiDataSourceLookup dataSourceLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
        return dataSourceLookup.getDataSource(jndiName);
    }

    @Bean()
    @Qualifier("oracleJdbcTemplate")
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() {
        return new JdbcTemplate(OracleDataSource());
    }
}
```

DemoController.java

```
package com.ankit.demo.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.ankit.demo.source.IDemoService;
import com.ankit.demo.vo.Employee;

 @RestController
 public class DemoController {

    @Autowired
    private IDemoService iDemoService;

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/getEmployee")

    public List<Employee> getEmployee() {
        return iDemoService.getEmployee();
    }
}
```

DemoDAOImpl.java

```
package com.ankit.demo.respository;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.ankit.demo.rowmapper.EmployeeMapper;
import com.ankit.demo.source.IDemoDAO;
import com.ankit.demo.vo.Employee;

@Component
public class DemoDAOImpl implements IDemoDAO {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("oracleJdbcTemplate")
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    @Override
    public List<Employee> getEmployee() {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE";
        List<Employee> empLst = null;
        try {
            empLst = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new EmployeeMapper());
        }catch(Exception ex) {

        }
        return empLst;
    }

}
```

EmployeeMapper.java

```
package com.ankit.demo.rowmapper;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;

import com.ankit.demo.vo.Employee;

public class EmployeeMapper<T> implements RowMapper<Employee>{

    @Override
    public Employee mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException   {

        Employee emp = new Employee();
        try {
            if(rs != null) {
                if(rs.next()) {
                   emp.setEmpId(rs.getLong("EMP_ID"));
                   emp.setEmpName(rs.getString("EMP_NAME"));
                   emp.setAccName(rs.getNString("ACCOUNT_NAME"));
                   emp.setJoinDate(rs.getDate("JOINING_DATE"));
                }
            }else {
                System.out.println("Result Set is null");
            }
        }catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            if(rs != null) {
                rs.close();
            }
        }
        return emp;
    }

}
```

DemoServiceImpl.java

```
package com.ankit.demo.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.ankit.demo.source.IDemoDAO;
import com.ankit.demo.source.IDemoService;
import com.ankit.demo.vo.Employee;

public class DemoServiceImpl implements IDemoService {

    @Autowired
    private IDemoDAO iDemoDAO;

    @Override
    public List<Employee> getEmployee() {
        return iDemoDAO.getEmployee();
    }

}
```

Employee.java

```
package com.ankit.demo.vo;

import java.util.Date;

public class Employee {

    private long empId;
    private String empName;
    private String accName;
    private Date joinDate;

    public long getEmpId() {
        return empId;
    }
    public void setEmpId(long empId) {
        this.empId = empId;
    }
    public String getEmpName() {
        return empName;
    }
    public void setEmpName(String empName) {
        this.empName = empName;
    }
    public String getAccName() {
        return accName;
    }
    public void setAccName(String accName) {
        this.accName = accName;
    }
    public Date getJoinDate() {
        return joinDate;
    }
    public void setJoinDate(Date joinDate) {
        this.joinDate = joinDate;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [empId=" + empId + ", empName=" + empName + ",  accName=" + accName + ", joinDate=" + joinDate
            + "]";
    }
}
```

server.xml

```
<server description="new server">

<!-- Enable features -->
<featureManager>
    <feature>webProfile-7.0</feature>
    <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
    <feature>jaxb-2.2</feature>
</featureManager>

<!-- To access this server from a remote client add a host attribute to 
    the following element, e.g. host="*" -->
<httpEndpoint httpPort="9080" httpsPort="9443"
    id="defaultHttpEndpoint" />

<!-- Automatically expand WAR files and EAR files -->
<applicationManager autoExpand="true" />
<applicationMonitor updateTrigger="mbean" />

<!-- WEB APPLICATION -->
<webApplication id="test-demo" location="test-demo.war" name="test-demo" />

<!-- ORACLE DATASOURCE -->
<dataSource id="DefaultDataSource" jndiName="jdbc/oracle" connectionSharing="MatchOriginalRequest" isolationLevel="TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED" statementCacheSize="20">
    <connectionManager maxPoolSize="20" minPoolSize="5" connectionTimeout="30s" agedTimeout="30m"></connectionManager>
    <jdbcDriver libraryRef="OracleLib" />
    <properties.oracle URL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/xe" user="system" password="{xor}PjsyNjE=" />
</dataSource>

<!-- ORACLE JDBC DRIVER LIBRARY -->
<library id="OracleLib">
    <file name="E:/LocalRepository/.m2/repository/com/oracle/ojdbc6/11.2.0.3/ojdbc6.jar" />
</library>
</server>
```

output console

```
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host):  http://localhost:9080/test-demo/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0003I: The application test-demo updated in 8.963 seconds.
[WARNING ] CWNEN0047W: Resource annotations on the fields of the org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer$CompositeELResolverImpl class will be ignored. The annotations could not be obtained because of the exception : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tiles/el/ScopeELResolver
[WARNING ] CWNEN0049W: Resource annotations on the methods of the org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer$CompositeELResolverImpl class will be ignored. The annotations could not be obtained because of the exception : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tiles/el/ScopeELResolver
[WARNING ] SRVE0190E: File not found: /getEmployee
```

I changed my spring-boot-starter-parent version to 1.3.3 and got below exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not evaluate condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration#propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer due to org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate not found. Make sure your own configuration does not rely on that class. This can also happen if you are @ComponentScanning a springframework package (e.g. if you put a @ComponentScan in the default package by mistake)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:55) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:102) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:178) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:140) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:116) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:333) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:98) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:678) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:520) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:149) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:129) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:85) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175) [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initializeServletContainerInitializers(WebApp.java:2490) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.18.jar:na]
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:1002) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.18.jar:na]
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:6550) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.18.jar:na]
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.startWebApp(DynamicVirtualHost.java:469) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.18.jar:na]
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.startWebApplication(DynamicVirtualHost.java:464) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.18.jar:na]
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.WebContainer.startWebApplication(WebContainer.java:1119) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.18.jar:na]
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.WebContainer.access$000(WebContainer.java:103) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.18.jar:na]
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.WebContainer$2.run(WebContainer.java:931) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.18.jar:na]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_151]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_151]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_151]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)  [na:1.8.0_151]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_151]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:609) ~[spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:521) ~[spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:507) ~[spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:567) ~[spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:683) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:627) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1445) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:975) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry$OptimizedBeanTypeRegistry.addBeanTypeForNonAliasDefinition(BeanTypeRegistry.java:289) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry$OptimizedBeanTypeRegistry.addBeanType(BeanTypeRegistry.java:278) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry$OptimizedBeanTypeRegistry.getNamesForType(BeanTypeRegistry.java:259) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:182) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:171) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:139) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:113) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate
at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findClassCommonLibraryClassLoaders(AppClassLoader.java:504) ~[na:na]
at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findClass(AppClassLoader.java:276) ~[na:na]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findOrDelegateLoadClass(AppClassLoader.java:482) ~[na:na]
at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.loadClass(AppClassLoader.java:443) ~[na:na]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
... 51 common frames omitted

2018-04-17 23:55:39.228  INFO 5692 --- [utor-thread-104] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: unknown
```

Comment: what URL are you making a request at?  is it `http://localhost:9080/test-demo/getEmployee`?  Also, those NoClassDefFoundErrors in your console output are likely causing issues.  Normally this occurs if a library is missing from your WAR, or if it has conflicts with classes that one of your liberty features is trying to provide to your application.

Comment: I am using the URL which you mentioned, I have added my server.xml above could you please verify whether it is a correct way of doing or not...The URL is creating problem only if I am adding datasource configuration in server.xml. I think my configuration might be wrong...or may be the initialization is not correct

Comment: you could try adding a print statement to `OracleDatabaseConfiguration` to verify that the JNDI name config is being injected properly.  The value of the `OracleDatabaseConfiguration.jndiName` field should be `jdbc/oracle` if everything is set up properly.

Comment: I am reading @Value("${spring.Oracle.datasource.jndi-name}") from application.properties file......the entries in application.properties are         spring.Oracle.datasource.jndi-name=jdbc/oracle
spring.datasource.initialize=false......also nothing is printing on console of sysout....that means my initialization is not correct i guess

Comment: You have `ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate`, so your dependency is somehow incorrect. Check if after building you have spring-jdbc jars in the WEB-INF/lib in the target folder.

Comment: I am using maven to download dependencies, the dependency jar is downloaded and its there in Maven Dependencies library. Do i need to add the same jars in WEB-INF/lib also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the issues which i was facing. Please find below steps which I've done.

1. Added all spring related(*spring-core,spring-beans,spring-jdbc, etc.*) jar to **WEB-INF/lib** folder.
2. Added **@Component** Annotations wherever I missed, because application was giving bean not defined for @Autowired.
3. Removed '**isolationLevel="TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED"**' from **server.xml**. This was earlier set and because of this I was getting **'could not get JDBC connection exception'**.
4. Added feature *'jndi-1.0','jdbc-4.1','jpa-2.1'* in **server.xml**

I don't know whether this is workaround or exact solution but it really worked for me.

Please correct me in case this is just a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to **"application.properties"** file:

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
```

Comment: I don't think this will resolve OPs issue. To me it looks like some dependencies are not met. What you are proposing here is just enabling features of the H2 database.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).